# Bind individual elements of collection in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

It is WPF application and I’m trying to bind individual collection item property in TextBlock. I search on StackOverflow and many others have asked similar questions and they have their solution working. I tried to access value same way but somehow, it’s not displaying Index value in my case so posting similar question. Please help me to identify what I'm doing wrong here.

**View model**

```
public class SequeanceViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Sequence> SequenceList = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel.Sequence>();
    public SequeanceViewModel()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            SequenceList.Add(new ViewModel.Sequence() { Index = i, Name = "Name goes here" });
        }
    }
}

public class Sequence : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int index { get; set; }
    private bool current { get; set; }
    private string name;
    public int Index
    {
        get
        {
            return index;
        }
        set
        {
            index = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Index"));
        }
    }
    public bool Current
    {
        get
        {
            return current;
        }
        set
        {
            current = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Current"));
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Window code**

```
SequeanceViewModel sequeanceViewModel;
public Validation()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    sequeanceViewModel = new SequeanceViewModel();
    this.DataContext = sequeanceViewModel;

}
```

**Binding in xaml**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SequenceList[0].Index, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: your public properties needs to have getters to make the binding work: public ObservableCollection<Sequence> SequenceList {get;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can only bind to public properties, you must define `SequenceList` as a property and not as a public field:

```
public ObservableCollection<Sequence> SequenceList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel.Sequence>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must expose SequenceList as a property instead of a public variable. Otherwise you cannot bind to it.